# How to use MySQL's DECODE function in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's pretend, I have the following table named "table1":

```
id      encoded_data
--------------------
1       hkhgkj23h42
2       872dskksadh
```

The encoded_data column is encoded with [the MySQL ENCODE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode) using the password string "mypassword".

In MySQL I would do something like this to get the decoded data:

```
SELECT
  DECODE(encoded_data, 'mypassword') AS decoded_data
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  id = 1
```

How can I do the same in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
  DB::table('table1')->select(array(DB::raw("DECODE(encoded_data, 'mypassword') AS decoded_data")))
      ->where('id', '=', 1)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but looks terrible somehow :) For retreiving only the value, not the whole row, I now use the [pluck function](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)